# How to load GooglePlaces Photo into UITableViewCell UIImageView

Tags: swift3, google-places-api, google-places

I have GooglePlace PlaceIDs and am trying to figure out how to load place photos into a UITableView.  The sample code that Google provides shows how to load a single UIImageView, and this works fine:

```
func loadFirstPhotoForPlace(placeID: String) {
        GMSPlacesClient.shared().lookUpPhotos(forPlaceID: placeID) { (photos, error) -> Void in
            if let error = error {
                // TODO: handle the error.
                print("Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            } else {
                if let firstPhoto = photos?.results.first {
                    self.loadImageForMetadata(photoMetadata: firstPhoto)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    func loadImageForMetadata(photoMetadata: GMSPlacePhotoMetadata) {
        GMSPlacesClient.shared().loadPlacePhoto(photoMetadata, callback: {
            (photo, error) -> Void in
            if let error = error {
                // TODO: handle the error.
                print("Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            } else {
                print("Loading Image")
                self.checkInImageView.image = photo;
         //       self.attributionTextView.attributedText = photoMetadata.attributions;
            }
        })
    }
```

I can't figure out from the documentation how to download a Place Photo directly.  One of many failed attempts:

```
    if let placeID = checkins[indexPath.row].placeID {
       GMSPlacesClient.shared().lookUpPhotos(forPlaceID: placeID) { (photos, error) -> Void in
       if let firstPhoto = photos?.results.first {
          cell.thumbnailImageView.image = firstPhoto
       }
    }

    }
  return cell
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get an array of photo IDs `photos[]` from **Google's Place Detail** API corresponding to a particular `placeID`.

> photos[] — an array of photo objects, each containing a reference to
>   an image. A Place Details request may return up to ten photos. More
>   information about place photos and how you can use the images in your
>   application can be found in the Place Photos documentation. A photo
>   object is described as:
>
> photo_reference — a string used to identify the photo when you perform a Photo request.
>
> height — the maximum height of the image.
>
> width — the maximum width of the image.
>
> html_attributions[] — contains any required attributions. This field will always be present, but may be empty.

You can look at the documentation here: https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/details

Now to get photo corresponding to a `photoID`, use **Google's Place Photo** API.

You can find the documentation here: https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/photos

**Example:**

To load an image corresponding to a `photoID` in `UITableViewCell's` `imageView`:

```
    let urlString = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/photo?maxwidth=\(Int(UIScreen.main.bounds.width))&photoreference=\(photoID)&key=API_KEY"

    if let url = URL(string: urlString)
    {
        let urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url)
        NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(urlRequest, queue: OperationQueue.main, completionHandler: {(response, data, error) in
            if let data = data
            {
                let image = UIImage(data: data)
                cell.photoImageView.image = image
            }
            else
            {
                cell.photoImageView.image = UIImage(named: "PlaceholderImage")
            }
        })
    }
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your help.  This is great!